# Send news feed with the new facebook.php class

Tags: facebook, duplicates, feed

Hi i'm new developer of fb apps and i want to know how can i send a message to the wall of my friends using the new facebook.php class http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

I do it this

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/',
    'post',
    array($ids,'message' => 'Playing around with FB Graph..')
);

This code work for the firts time i can login in the application after i try to enter again and the application sending and error The message if duplicated.

How can i fixed or what if the best way to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having is because facebook wont let you send the same message to the same user multiple times hence the error duplicate message. Change the text of the message and the message will work.